# Куки работают в селекте, а перехода по ссылке нет

Tags: html

При выборе из списка должно переходить на другую страницу и записывать выбранное.
А оно только записывает, какую опцию я выбрал, но не делает переход по заданной ссылке.

примечание:

когда ставишь яваскрипт с кодом впереди селекта, то при выборе опции оно запускает ссылку, но не записывает в куки.

```js
    var select = document.getElementById('site');
select.onchange = function () {
 
    // задаём время, через которое наш cookie истечёт
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
 
    // записываем cookie
    document.cookie = 'site=' + select.value + '; path=/; expires=' + date.toUTCString();
};
 
 
                // возвращает cookie с именем name, если есть, если нет, то undefined
function getCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
            "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
    ));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}
 
 
var select = document.getElementById('site'),
cookie = getCookie('site');
 
        if (cookie) {
    select.value = cookie;
}
```

```html
 <select data-placeholder="Введите ваш..." class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2" size=1 onChange="top.location=this.value" id="site" name="site">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="/kiss">kiss</option>
            <option value="/gav">gav</option>
    
</select>
```